# MVC 3 "is incompatible with .NET Framework 4"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Not sure how even that could be possible, but I have got this error message:

[image: System.Web.Mvc Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is incompatible with .NET Framework 4 In order to add it you should to change the project's target to a compatible framework first]

That happened after I've:

1. installed .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 Professional
2. installed VS 2010 SP1 package using WPI + NuGet + some groovy funky library packages
3. installed *ASP.NET MVC 3 (includes April 2011 Tools Update)* package using WPI
4. **created a new empty MVC 3 C# Web Application with Razor support**
5. failed to build it because got this error:    `Warning  3   The primary reference "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".`
6. checked if the project targets .NET 4. It does
7. removed the reference to *System.Web.Mvc* and tried to add it again (version 3.0) and got the aforementioned error message (screenshot above)
8. tried out re-installing some components, performed some of the previous steps in random order, spilled some virgin chicken's blood over my computer and restarted Windows again and again, all that to no avail.

I bet the solution is banal, but it must be that its Friday afternoon.

By the way, I have also VS 2008, MVC 1, MVC 2, all .NET framework versions installed and functional.

---

**Update 1:**
In fact, I have exactly the same problem with **MVC 2** projects targeting .NET 4.

---

**Update 2:** I feel that this is somehow related - I do really miss **System.Data.Linq.dll** in the folder `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` (though **System.Data.Linq.xml** is present)

I reinstalled .NET 4 framework but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but did you make sure your project references System.Data.Linq?

Comment: Does the project target `.NET4`, or `.NET4 Client Profile`? The client profile is a cut-down version of .NET 4, and doesn't include some key libraries.

Comment: @Gregory: tried to add it but it does not appear in the _Add Reference_  list. I've got this already added: _System.Data_ (4.0), _System.Data.DataSetExtensions_ (4.0), _System.Data.Entity_ (4.0). Other System.Data.* components are about Entity.Design, Services and Sql.

Comment: @RB is right I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Maxim, it's not something to 'add' but a change in the build target.

Comment: @RB: in my project properties, Application tab, Target framework I see _.NET Framework 4_. Moreover, all references to _System.Something_ have _4.0.0.0_ version.

Comment: Sounds like you might be missing a service pack in there. Have you tried the normal download version of the VS 2010 SP1 installer? That one also includes .net 4 SP1.

Comment: @Tridus: I have VS version _10.0.40219.1 SP 1Rel_, my colleagues too and they have it working without problems. I will however try your solution

Comment: Any resolution to this issue?

Comment: Reinstallation of VS2010 SP1 from ISO didn't help :(

Comment: You reinstalled, but did you at one time install a beta? I remember having to scrape the async CTP from my system before I could install MVC3. Worst case: uninstall VS2010 _and_ Fx4

Comment: @Henk: yes, I had Async CTP installed and had to remove it too prior to installing MVC3. Something is just broken on my system since. Now just need time to reinstall everything again...

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar problem (unable to add a reference) with a different dll. Clearing the list of recently added references did help.

Answer (score 1):

Manually uninstall MVC3, Download Microsoft Web Platform Installer and reinstall MVC3 through WPI - that usually does a pretty good job of ensuring prerequisites are present.

Comment: tried it, didn't help. Seems like I have a broken .NET 4 installation - I have the same problem with MVC 2 projects, and I have System.Data.Linq missing in my .NET 4 assemblies folder. Will try to reinstall .NET 4 from the standalone installer.

Comment: I sympathise - I tend to install everything through WPI now - may be worth uninstalling everything it handles and letting it put it all back together for you.

Answer (score 1):

this question is a little old... but if anyone else have the same message when adding a reference to a project this can be a good solution:

I downloaded PowerCommands for vs2010
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99

it allows to copy a reference from one project to another, I do this and this works... IO suppose that editing the project file manually can work too (not tested)